# How to correctly handle data management with SharedPreferences?

Tags: json, android-studio, youtube-api, sharedpreferences, android-volley

Right now, I am in the process of "optimizing" my app. I am still a beginner, so what I am doing is basically moving methods from my MainActivity.class to their separate class. I believe it's called `Encapsulation` *(Please correct me if I'm wrong)*.

My application needs to :

1. Get a YouTube Playlist Link from the YouTube App (with an Intent, `android.intent.action.SEND`).
2. Use the link to fetch data from the Google Servers with the YouTubeApi and Volley.
3. Read the data received and add it to an `arrayList<String>`.

What my `YouTubeUsage.java` class is supposed to do, is fetch data with the YouTubeApi and Volley then store the data using SharedPreferences. Once the data is saved, the data is being read in my `ConvertActivity.class` (It's an activity specifically created for `android.intent.action.SEND`) with my method `getVideoIds()` before setting an adapter for my listView in my `createRecyclerView()` method.

**YouTubeUsage.java**

```
public class YoutubeUsage {

    private Boolean results = false;
    private String mResponse;
    private ArrayList<String> videoIds = new ArrayList<>();
    String Url;

    public String getUrl(String signal) {
        String playlistId = signal.substring(signal.indexOf("=") + 1);
        this.Url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails%2C%20snippet%2C%20id&playlistId=" +
                playlistId + "&maxResults=25&key=" + "API_KEY";

        return this.Url;
    }            

    public void fetch(String Url, final Context context){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        sharedPreferences(response, context);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VolleyError", Objects.requireNonNull(error.getMessage()));
            }
        });
        queue.add(request);
    }
    private void sharedPreferences(String response, Context context){
        SharedPreferences m = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = m.edit();
        if (m.contains("serverResponse")){
            if (!m.getString("serverResponse", "").equals(response)){
                editor.remove("serverResponse");
                editor.apply();
                updateSharedPreferences(response, context);
            }
        } else{
            updateSharedPreferences(response, context);
        }

    }
    private void updateSharedPreferences(String mResponse, Context mContext){
        SharedPreferences m = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = m.edit();
        editor.putString("serverResponse", mResponse);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

**ConvertActivity.java**

```
public class ConvertActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    YoutubeUsage youtubeUsage = new YoutubeUsage();
    ArrayList<String> videoIDs = new ArrayList<>();

    String Url = "";

    ListView listView;
    MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview_convert);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        if ("android.intent.action.SEND".equals(action) && "text/plain".equals(type)) {
            Url = youtubeUsage.getUrl(Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT")));
        }
        //I would like to avoid the try/catch below       
        try {
            videoIDs = getVideoIDs(Url, this);
            createRecyclerView(videoIDs);
            Log.i("ResponseVideoIDs", String.valueOf(videoIDs.size()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getVideoIDs(String Url, Context context) throws JSONException {
        ArrayList<String> rawVideoIDs = new ArrayList<>();
        youtubeUsage.fetch(Url, context);
        SharedPreferences m = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String serverResponse = m.getString("serverResponse", "");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(serverResponse);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject jsonVideoId =  jsonObject1.getJSONObject("contentDetails");
            rawVideoIDs.add(jsonVideoId.getString("videoId"));
        }
        return rawVideoIDs;
    }
    private void createRecyclerView(ArrayList<String> videoIDs){
        myCustomAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, videoIDs);
        listView.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
        myCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Everything works fine, however, my sharedPreferences never gets updated. Which means, if I share a YouTube playlist from the YouTube App to my app with 3 items in it, it will work fine. The Listview will show 3 items with their corresponding IDs as it should. But, if I share a YouTube playlist again, my app will still hold on to the data of the previous playlist I shared (even if I close it), showing the item number and the IDs of the previous link. If i continue to share the same playlist over and over, it will eventually show the correct number of items and the correct IDs.

I could totally put all my methods from the `YouTubeUsage.java` in my `ConvertActivity.class` preventing me from using SharedPreferences to transfer data between the two java classes. However, JSON throws an exception. That means I have to encapsulate my code with try/catch. I would like to avoid those since I need to do a lot of operations on the data just received by Volley (check a class size, look for certains strings). I find that doing this in these try/catch don't work like I want. (i.e. outside the try/catch, the values remains the same even if I updated them in the try/catch).

I want to know two things.

1. How can I correct this problem?
2. Is this the most efficient way to do this (optimization)? *(I though of maybe
   converting the VolleyResponse to a string with Gson then store the String file, but I don't know if that's the best way to do it since it's supposed to be 
   provisional data. It feels like just more of the same).*

Thank You!

Comment: Can I suggest a simplification to start with?  In your `fetch` method, replace line `sharedPreferences(response, context)` with `updateSharedPreferences(response, context)`, then delete method `sharedPreferences`.  The result will be identifcal, but the flow will be much clearer.  Secondly, is your `onResponse` method being called successfully, as and when you'd expect it and with a meaningful `response` String; put a `Log.d()` in the first line of this method to check.

Comment: I replaced `sharedPreferences(response, context)` with `updateSharedPreferences(response, context)`. The `onResponse` method is called correctly : I checked with a `Log.d("ResponseCheck", response);` and it returns the complete JSON File. However, `android.intent.action.SEND` needs to be called multiple times before it actually shows the response in the logcat. The JSON is not updated if I use a different YouTube link with `android.intent.action.SEND`. I'm confused as to why it does that. Is it because of the SharedPreferences or the Volley Request?

Comment: Perhaps your RequestQueue is falling out of scope before the response is received. Put the declaration `RequestQueue queue;` at class level rather than within your `fetch` method.

Comment: I have put `RequestQueue queue;` at class level (below `public class YouTubeUsage{`) and changed the first line of the `fetch` method with `queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);`. As of now, the JSON does not get updated when the app is running in the background (When I'm multitasking. I should probably implement `OnPause`?) but it does get updated when I close the app and open it again. However, even though I receive the correct response from Volley, the recyclerView still shows data from the previous response... It only shows the correct data when I close the app and do it again...

Comment: Try moving your call to `createRecyclerView` to your Activity's `onResume` method.

Comment: The problem remains. Now, the RecyclerView does not update at all. I have to restart the app two times before it shows the correct items. I created `@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        createRecyclerView(videoIDs);
    }` is this the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with making assumptions about order of events.  Volley will handle requests asynchronously, so it is advisable to implement the observer pattern here.

Create a new Java file that just contains:

```
interface MyNetworkResponse {
   void goodResponse(String responseString);
}
```

Then make sure `ConvertActivity` `implements MyNetworkResponse` and create method:

```
void goodResponse(String responseString) {
   // handle a positive response here, i.e. extract the JSON and send to your RecyclerView.
}
```

within your Activity.

In your `YoutubeUsage` constructor, pass in the Activity context (YoutubeUsage) and then store this in a `YoutubeUsage` instance variable called `ctx`.

In `onCreate`, create an instance of `YoutubeUsage` and pass in `this`.

In `onResponse` just call `ctx.goodResponse(response)`.

Amend the following block to:

```
if ("android.intent.action.SEND".equals(action) && "text/plain".equals(type)) {
        Url = youtubeUsage.getUrl(Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT")));
        youtubeUsage.fetch(Url);
}
```

Delete the `try/catch` from `onCreate`.

And no need to use `SharedPreferences` at all.

UPDATE

Try this code:

MyNetworkResponse.java

```
interface MyNetworkResponse {
    void goodResponse(String responseString);
    void badResponse(VolleyError error);
}
```

YoutubeUsage.java

```
class YoutubeUsage {

private RequestQueue queue;
private MyNetworkResponse callback;

YoutubeUsage(Object caller) {
    this.callback = (MyNetworkResponse) caller;
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue((Context) caller);
}

static String getUrl(String signal) {
    String playlistId = signal.substring(signal.indexOf("=") + 1);
    return "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails%2C%20snippet%2C%20id&playlistId=" + playlistId + "&maxResults=25&key=" + "API_KEY";
}

void fetch(String url){
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    callback.goodResponse(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            callback.badResponse(error);
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}
```

}

ConvertActivity.java

```
public class ConvertActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyNetworkResponse {

YoutubeUsage youtubeUsage;
ArrayList<String> videoIDs = new ArrayList<>();

ListView listView;
MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview_convert);
    youtubeUsage = new YoutubeUsage(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if ("android.intent.action.SEND".equals(action) && "text/plain".equals(type)) {
        String url = YoutubeUsage.getUrl(Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT")));
        youtubeUsage.fetch(url);
    }
}

private ArrayList<String> getVideoIDs(String serverResponse) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<String> rawVideoIDs = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(serverResponse);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject jsonVideoId = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("contentDetails");
        rawVideoIDs.add(jsonVideoId.getString("videoId"));
    }
    return rawVideoIDs;
}

private void createRecyclerView(ArrayList<String> videoIDs) {
    myCustomAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, videoIDs);
    listView.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
    myCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void goodResponse(String responseString) {
    Log.d("Convert:goodResp", "[" + responseString + "]");
    try {
        ArrayList<String> rawVideoIDs = getVideoIDs(responseString);
        createRecyclerView(rawVideoIDs);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // handle JSONException, e.g. malformed response from server.
    }
}

@Override
public void badResponse(VolleyError error) {
    // handle unwanted server response.
}
```

}

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly what I need to pass to the `YouTubeUsage` constructor. First of all, I created a constructor for `YouTubeUsage` and added `Context ctx;` at class level (`YouTubeUsage`). In my `ConvertActivity`, I called the YouTubeUsage class and pass `this` as an argument : `youtubeUsage = new YoutubeUsage(this);`. However, I don't understand how I can call `ctx.goodResponse(response)` in the Volley's `OnResponse`. Android Studio says : `Cannot resolve method "goodResponse(java.lang.String)"` Is `ctx` supposed to be a Context Object or a MyNetworkResponse Object?

Comment: `ctx` is of type `MyNetworkResponse`. Sorry if I was unclear. Was typing very fast! Call it something more meaningful. I was thinking of `Context`.